# extending RealmObject and implementing Observable on same class

Tags: android

I have a class like this

```
public class MyClass extends RealmObject implements Observable [

}
```

This problem is that when it generates all the Observable methods it breaks as it somehow conflicts with extending `RealmObject`. Is there a solution to this? I get the classic Android databinding error when I try to do the above, where android spits out a bunch of related errors as opposed to a single error.

Answer (score 0):

To solve you simply put `@Ignore` annotation before the `registry` property. Realm doesn't support serializing the registry. e.g.

```
@Ignore
private PropertyChangeRegistry registry =
        new PropertyChangeRegistry();
```